# Function that returns generic function pointers

Tags: rust

Say I have two functions:

```
fn function_with_one_argument(one: i64) -> bool{
    one==one // irrelevant
}

fn function_with_two_arguments(one: i64, two: i64) -> bool {
    one==two // irrelevant
}
```

Given a different input value, I'd like to return a different function pointer:

```
fn main() {
    println!("\n\n{:?}\n\n", get_function_pointer(1)(321));
    println!("{:?}", get_function_pointer(2)(321/*, 321*/));
}
```

How can I represent the return value to return a pointer to different shaped functions?

```
fn get_function_pointer(id: i64) -> /***/(fn(i64) -> bool)/***/ {
    match id {
        1 => function_with_one_argument,
        // 2 => function_with_two_arguments, /*How do we make this work?*?
        _ => panic!("!?!?!")
    }
}
```

Comment: The two functions do not even have the same prototype. `function_with_two_arguments` is not a `fn(i64) -> bool`. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @E_net4 I would like change the return type `get_function_pointer` to return a more generic signature for a function. The goal is to dynamically feed different shaped functions as test properties to quickcheck.

Comment: How would quickcheck call the function it receives?

Comment: Could you not replace the argument passed in with a single array or struct?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson quickcheck takes a function `where function is Testable`. Source is here: https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck/blob/master/src/tester.rs

Comment: `quickcheck<A>` is a generic function, meaning `A` must be resolved to a concrete type at compile time. If you *could* write `get_function_pointer`, it would [erase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) the type, which requires runtime polymorphism (i.e., some additional piece of runtime data about the type that gets passed around with it). You can't call `quickcheck`, a *compile-time-qualified* function, by using information that isn't available until runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an enum to represent the output of the function

```
enum Either<T, U> {
    Left(T),
    Right(U),
}

fn function_with_one_argument(one: i64) -> bool {
    one == one // irrelevant
}

fn function_with_two_arguments(one: i64, two: i64) -> bool {
    one == two // irrelevant
}

fn get_function_pointer(id: i64) -> Either<fn(i64) -> bool, fn(i64, i64) -> bool> {
    match id {
        1 => Either::Left(function_with_one_argument),
        2 => Either::Right(function_with_two_arguments),
        _ => panic!("!?!?!"),
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll play with it a bit! It could potentially get a little burdensome as the list of function signatures grows, but we might be limited without the concept of variadics.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete solution after using the suggestion above for `enum`.

```
extern crate quickcheck;
use quickcheck::{QuickCheck, Testable};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut property_map = HashMap::new();
    property_map.insert("one", Property::One { func: one_argument });
    property_map.insert("two", Property::Two { func: two_arguments });

    test_property("one", &property_map);
    test_property("two", &property_map);
}

enum Property {
    One { func: fn(i64) -> bool },
    Two { func: fn(i64, i64) -> bool },
}

fn test_property(property: &str, property_map: &HashMap<&str, Property>) {
    match property_map.get(property) {
        Some(p) => fetch_property_and_run_quickcheck(p),
        None => println!("No matching property in property_map"),
    };
}

fn fetch_property_and_run_quickcheck(property: &Property) {
    match *property {
        Property::One { func: prop_to_test } => run_quickcheck(prop_to_test),
        Property::Two { func: prop_to_test } => run_quickcheck(prop_to_test),
    };
}

fn run_quickcheck<A>(property: A)
    where A: Testable
{
    QuickCheck::new().quickcheck(property);
}

fn one_argument(one: i64) -> bool {
    println!("testing one_argument() with {}", one);
    one == one // irrelevant
}

fn two_arguments(one: i64, two: i64) -> bool {
    println!("testing two_arguments() with {} and {}", one, two);
    one == one && two == two // irrelevant
}
```